# Schema validation failed; XML does not comply with UBL 2.1 standards in line with ZATCA specifications

Tags: python, django, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to use validate my xml with UBL 2.1 standards in line with Saudi Arabia ZATCA(Zakat, Tax and Customs Authority) specifications.The url of this validatoe : https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML .But I can't validate that as my xml looking great but I don't understand what's going wrong .I used python json2xml package for creating xml.This package generate xml from json.

Erros list what I am getting from ZATCA XML Validator:

**category : XSD_SCHEMA_ERROR**

**code :SAXParseException**

**message : Schema validation failed; XML does not comply with UBL 2.1 standards in line with ZATCA specifications**

Here is my Xml code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Invoice>
    <ProfileID>reporting:1.0</ProfileID>
    <ID>INV004</ID>
    <UUID>fd5a7cc4-2316-49ee-ac07-6f4be4be3731</UUID>
    <IssueDate>2022-08-13</IssueDate>
    <IssueTime>23:46:07</IssueTime>
    <InvoiceTypeCode>388</InvoiceTypeCode>
    <InvoiceTypeCodeName>0101001</InvoiceTypeCodeName>
    <DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</TaxCurrencyCode>
    <Note/>
    <OrderReference>
        <ID/>
    </OrderReference>
    <ContractDocumentReference>
        <ID/>
    </ContractDocumentReference>
    <AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <UUID>4</UUID>
        <PIH>
            <Attachment>
                <EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>ET05jV7roub7D66wOAQ49TQ8mCkyldhmH7B8CV3Rc6g=</EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
            </Attachment>
        </PIH>
        <QR>
            <Attachment>
                <EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>5D6ZU7f6nb+s1szmMw46l4NZ7yTy0p1wi0ZUMsdQWBE=</EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
            </Attachment>
        </QR>
    </AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <Signature>
        <ID>urn:oasis:names:specification: ubl:signature:Invoice</ID>
        <SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped: xades</SignatureMethod>
    </Signature>
    <AccountingSupplierParty>
        <Party>
            <PartyLegalEntity>
                <RegistrationName>Altaf Miazee</RegistrationName>
            </PartyLegalEntity>
            <PartyIdentification>
                <ID/>
            </PartyIdentification>
            <PartyTaxScheme>
                <CompanyID>300600363600003</CompanyID>
            </PartyTaxScheme>
            <PostalAddress>
                <Country>
                    <IdentificationCode>BD</IdentificationCode>
                </Country>
                <AdditionalStreetName>Altafbari</AdditionalStreetName>
                <StreetName>dhaka</StreetName>
                <BuildingNumber>1233</BuildingNumber>
                <PlotIdentification>1233</PlotIdentification>
                <CityName>Dhaka</CityName>
                <PostalZone>12302</PostalZone>
                <CountrySubentity>Dhaka</CountrySubentity>
                <CitySubdivisionName>miazee</CitySubdivisionName>
            </PostalAddress>
        </Party>
    </AccountingSupplierParty>
    <AccountingCustomerParty>
        <Party>
            <PartyLegalEntity>
                <RegistrationName>Hosen MD Altaf</RegistrationName>
            </PartyLegalEntity>
            <PartyIdentification>
                <ID>398765409876333</ID>
            </PartyIdentification>
            <PartyTaxScheme>
                <CompanyID>398765409876333</CompanyID>
            </PartyTaxScheme>
            <PostalAddress>
                <StreetName>الملك سلمان</StreetName>
                <AdditionalStreetName>الملك سلمان</AdditionalStreetName>
                <BuildingNumber>1234</BuildingNumber>
                <PlotIdentification>1234</PlotIdentification>
                <CityName>dhaka</CityName>
                <PostalZone>12234</PostalZone>
                <CountrySubentity>Dhaka</CountrySubentity>
                <CitySubdivisionName>الملك سلمان</CitySubdivisionName>
                <Country>
                    <IdentificationCode>BD</IdentificationCode>
                </Country>
            </PostalAddress>
        </Party>
    </AccountingCustomerParty>
    <Delivery>
        <ActualDeliveryDate>2022-08-25</ActualDeliveryDate>
        <LatestDeliveryDate/>
    </Delivery>
    <PaymentMeans>
        <PaymentMeansCode>10</PaymentMeansCode>
        <PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <PaymentNote/>
        </PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </PaymentMeans>
    <AllowanceCharge>
        <TaxCategory>
            <ID>S</ID>
            <Percent>0.0</Percent>
            <TaxScheme>
                <ID>VAT</ID>
            </TaxScheme>
        </TaxCategory>
        <ChargeIndicator>False</ChargeIndicator>
        <MultiplierFactorNumeric>52.1</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <AmountcurrencyID>SAR</AmountcurrencyID>
        <BaseAmount>164263.68</BaseAmount>
        <BaseAmountcurrencyID>SAR</BaseAmountcurrencyID>
    </AllowanceCharge>
    <LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <LineExtensionAmount>164263.68</LineExtensionAmount>
        <LineExtensionAmountCurrencyID>SAR</LineExtensionAmountCurrencyID>
        <AllowanceTotalAmount>0.00</AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <AllowanceTotalAmountcurrencyID>SAR</AllowanceTotalAmountcurrencyID>
        <TaxExclusiveAmount>146664.00</TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <TaxExclusiveAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxExclusiveAmountcurrencyID>
        <TaxInclusiveAmount>164263.68</TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <TaxInclusiveAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxInclusiveAmountcurrencyID>
        <PrepaidAmount/>
        <PrepaidAmountcurrencyID>SAR</PrepaidAmountcurrencyID>
        <PayableAmount>164263.68</PayableAmount>
        <PayableAmountcurrencyID>SAR</PayableAmountcurrencyID>
    </LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <TaxTotal>
        <TaxAmount>17599.68</TaxAmount>
        <VatAmountCurrency>SAR</VatAmountCurrency>
        <VatAmountInAccountingCurrency>17599.68</VatAmountInAccountingCurrency>
        <CurrencyForVatAmountInAccountingCurrency>SAR</CurrencyForVatAmountInAccountingCurrency>
        <TaxSubtotal>
            <TaxableAmount>146664.0</TaxableAmount>
            <TaxableAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxableAmountcurrencyID>
            <TaxCategory>
                <ID>E</ID>
                <Percent>1</Percent>
                <TaxExemptionReasonCode>TYIEWE</TaxExemptionReasonCode>
                <TaxExemptionReason>lksdkskak</TaxExemptionReason>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <ID>10.12</ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </TaxCategory>
            <TaxAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxAmountcurrencyID>
        </TaxSubtotal>
        <TaxAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxAmountcurrencyID>
    </TaxTotal>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <item>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <InvoicedQuantity>12</InvoicedQuantity>
            <InvoicedQuantityUnitCode>nos</InvoicedQuantityUnitCode>
            <LineExtensionAmount>146664.0</LineExtensionAmount>
            <LineExtensionAmountcurrencyID>SAR</LineExtensionAmountcurrencyID>
            <AllowanceCharge>
                <ChargeIndicator>False</ChargeIndicator>
                <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.0</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
                <Amount>0</Amount>
                <AmountcurrencyID>SAR</AmountcurrencyID>
                <BaseAmount>146664.0</BaseAmount>
                <BaseAmountcurrencyID>SAR</BaseAmountcurrencyID>
            </AllowanceCharge>
            <TaxTotal>
                <TaxAmount>17599.68</TaxAmount>
                <TaxAmountcurrencyID>SAR</TaxAmountcurrencyID>
                <RoundingAmount>164263.68</RoundingAmount>
                <RoundingAmountcurrencyID>SAR</RoundingAmountcurrencyID>
            </TaxTotal>
            <Item>
                <Name>altaf</Name>
                <BuyersItemIdentification>
                    <ID/>
                </BuyersItemIdentification>
                <SellersItemIdentification>
                    <ID>ITM9</ID>
                </SellersItemIdentification>
                <StandardItemIdentification>
                    <ID/>
                </StandardItemIdentification>
                <ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <Percent>12.00</Percent>
                    <TaxScheme>
                        <ID>VAT</ID>
                    </TaxScheme>
                </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            </Item>
            <Price>
                <PriceAmount>12222.00</PriceAmount>
                <PriceAmountschemeID>SAR</PriceAmountschemeID>
                <AllowanceCharge>
                    <ChargeIdicator>False</ChargeIdicator>
                    <Amount>0</Amount>
                    <AmountcurrencyID>SAR</AmountcurrencyID>
                    <BaseAmount>164263.68</BaseAmount>
                    <BaseAmountcurrencyID>SAR</BaseAmountcurrencyID>
                </AllowanceCharge>
                <BaseQuantity>12</BaseQuantity>
                <BaseQuantityUnitCode/>
            </Price>
        </item>
    </InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Here is the python code I wrote for creating XML:

```
def download_invoice_xml(request, invoice_type, invoice_no):
in_data = InvoiceReport.objects.filter(invoice_type=invoice_type, invoice_number=invoice_no)
for inv in in_data:
    jsonData = inv.invoice_data
    mode = inv.creation_mode  

# Issuetime = jsonData['IssueTime']
# d1 = datetime.strptime(Issuetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# dt_to_string = d1.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
# jsonData['IssueTime'] = dt_to_string
#
# Issuedate = jsonData['IssueDate']
# d2 = datetime.strptime(Issuedate, "%Y-%m-%d")
# dt_to_string2 = d1.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
# jsonData['IssueDate'] = dt_to_string2
if jsonData.get('AllowanceCharge').get('ChargeIndicator') == 0:
    jsonData['AllowanceCharge']['ChargeIndicator'] = False
for i in jsonData.get('InvoiceLine'):
    if i.get('AllowanceCharge').get('ChargeIndicator') == 0:
        i['AllowanceCharge']['ChargeIndicator'] = False
    if i.get('Price').get('AllowanceCharge').get('ChargeIndicator') == 0:
        i['Price']['AllowanceCharge']['ChargeIndicator'] = False
xml_output = json2xml.Json2xml(jsonData, wrapper="Invoice", pretty=True, attr_type=False).to_xml()

now = datetime.now()
if xml_output:
    response = HttpResponse(xml_output, content_type='application/xml')
    xml_date = jsonData['IssueDate'].replace("-", "")
    xml_time = jsonData['IssueTime'].replace(":", "")
    filename = jsonData['AccountingSupplierParty']['Party']['PartyTaxScheme']['CompanyID'] + "_" + \
               xml_date + "T" + xml_time + "_" + str(jsonData['ID']) + ".xml"
    # filename = jsonData['AccountingSupplierParty']['Party']['PartyIdentification']['ID'] + "_%s_%s.xml" % (
    #     str((now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))), jsonData['ID'])      
    content = "attachment; filename=%s" % (filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content
    return response
return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

This is part of ZATCA E-invoice system and the project code is writen with python django.

Comment: I deleted that question already.Here I am generate xml .But The generated xml isn’t  Comply with UBL 2.1 version which I needed .But don’t find any way to resolve that

Comment: ZATCA(Zakat, Tax and Customs Authority) specifications.The url of this validatoe : https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML

Comment: The question is tagged "xsd". Where is the schema?

Comment: @HosenMDAltaf, have you got the correct XML file? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Not yet. I am creating my own package for UBL version xml in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UBL specifications that *aren't* met generally fall into two categories:

1. An Attribute is required but you are not providing it.
2. The order of the attributes inside the element is wrong.

To solve your problem, you should inspect each element of your XML against the UBL Schema specification and find required attributes that you're not providing or attributes out of order..

- Go to this site that lists the UBL Specifications:
  http://www.datypic.com/sc/ubl21/ss.html
- In the search box at the top, enter the name of the element followed by the word "Type" (e.g.: Invoice --> search for InvoiceType

[image]

- In the element specifications, find each attribute that its relationship starts with [1 .. this attribute is mandatory, make sure you provide a value for it.
  [image]
- Check the order of the attribute and make sure they are added in the correct order.
  [image]

Doing that will ensure that all your elements are compliant to the UBL specifications.

Comment: Thank you for details explains .Do you have any format of the valid UBL 2.1 version of xml.I look forward but don’t find any.

Comment: You're welcome,

If you find the answer helpful, please accept it as an answer to your question..

Here is an example invoice that passes the UBL specifications:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtaJtdUF4g4liddrcWYu0XHZnj_haA?e=TUBrmY

Comment: @Ahmad Kelany, Are you sure the XML you provided works with zatka?

Comment: @pepe, I am sure that is passes the UBL specifications as I said in the comment,

ZATCA specifications and their validation API are not complete at the date of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in : https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/
As the results in coding and sharing the invoice have many errors Zakat has been warned over and over again

Comment: So what approach we can follow .To validate xml ?